# git checkout last version of deleted file, if available

Tags: git

I have a repo where a file has been deleted locally, and when trying to restore by checking out the latest git commit I noted that the complete folder had been added to `.gitignore` at some point in the past.

The folder is only needed for the build process on the central machine, and all folder contents except the settings file were completely 3rd-party. To fix some issues, I deleted the folder and unpacked the 3rd party toolkit once again. Redoing the settings from scratch, and especially reissuing the access tokens included therein is laborious and expensive.

To get a head-start, how can I check out the last available version of that config file from my repo, or get the definitive answer that this file was never put into git server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git log -- path/to/file` to find the last commit that touched that file (before it was deleted).

Then, checkout that file from that commit. If the commit hash is `aabbcc`,

```
git checkout aabbcc -- path/to/file
```

Comment: 'git log --oneline -5 -- path/to/file' may save a little bit of screen space